# Yocto Error: "non debug package contains .debug directory" with yocto recipe

Tags: openembedded

I am trying to build a custom yocto recipe, which involves compiling a small C program. During the build -

```
$ bitbake -f interface-configuration
...
ERROR: QA Issue: non debug package contains .debug directory: interface-configuration path /work/cortexa9hf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/interface-configuration/0.1-r0/packages-split/interface-configuration/etc/interfaces/bin/.debug/set
ERROR: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/git/poky/build-atmel/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/interface-configuration/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.28986
ERROR: Task 10 (/home/git/poky/meta-atmel/recipes-intelli/interface-configuration/interface-configuration_0.1.bb, do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I was wondering if anyone on here know how to either disable debug info or remove the QA check. Google search for the error has proven fruitless so far.

Cheers

Update with interface-configuration.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Interface configuration files and tools"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=3f40d7994397109285ec7b81fdeb3b58"
SRC_URI = "file://interface-configuration-0.1.tar.gz"

do_compile() {
    install -vd ${D}/
    ${CC} -g0 set.c -o set
    # CC is arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/git/poky/build-atmel/tmp/sysroots/sama5d3xek
}


do_install() {
    cp -r ${S}/etc ${D}/etc
    install -vd ${D}/etc/interfaces/bin
    install -vm 0755 set ${D}/etc/interfaces/bin/
}

do_install_append() {
    # I added this to try to remove the error - it doesn't work
    rm -rf ${D}/etc/interfaces/bin/.debug
}

FILES_${PN} += "/etc/interfaces/MANIFEST \
    /etc/interfaces/conf/A \
    /etc/interfaces/conf/B \
    /etc/interfaces/conf/C \
    /etc/interfaces/conf/D \
    /etc/interfaces/template/A \
    /etc/interfaces/template/B \
    /etc/interfaces/template/C \
    /etc/interfaces/template/D \
    /set.c"
```

Comment: Please post your interface-configuration_0.1.bb. You put a debugging directory `/etc/interfaces/bin/.debug` in a non debugging package.

Comment: @silvio I have updated the description with the .bb

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yocto/OE generate a `.debug`-directory under the directory where the binary is placed. You use a non default directory for a binary (`install -vm 0755 set ${D}/etc/interfaces/bin`). You need to declare that .debug goes to the `-dbg` package.

You have two options now. First use of standard directory like `${D}/usr/bin` or second you add .debug to dbg - packages like this:

```
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "/etc/interfaces/bin/.debug"
```

You can remove your `do_install_append` because the `.debug` is created after `do_install`.

If you use the second option you have to need to configure your gdb with `set debug-file-directory directories` option in gdb to debug you binary. Read more [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)

Comment: Thank you for good information, but a small corretion as @Inmx said , .debug is generated from package not install

Answer (score 13):

The .debug directory is automatically generated as part of the `split_and_strip_files` function in [`meta/classes/package.bbclass`](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/package.bbclass) .

This function takes the files resulting from `do_install` and splits them up into multiple packages: `${PN}` containing the base files and stripped binaries, `${PN}-dbg` with debug symbols, etc.

You can suppress `split_and_strip_files` by adding the following to your `.bb` file:

```
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
```

I think you also want to simplify the list of packages generated from your `.bb` to:

```
PACKAGES = "${PN}"
```

Comment: This will be helpful when the user doesn't intent to create `PN-dbg`, Which is not the default case. Hence will have to handle the case for splitting them in different packages.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip all of your recipe package
you can add the below line to skip QA issue in your " .bb " file

for installed -vs-shiped  issue:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "installed-vs-shipped"
```

### for striping package issue :

```
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
```

hope this will work for you.